# Удалить родительский тег в xml полностью с содержимым

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

Есть xml:

```
   <authors>


<author lang="RU" num="1">

<lastname>Иванов</lastname>

<initials>Иван Иванович</initials>

</author>


<author lang="RU" num="2">

<lastname>Петров</lastname>

<initials>Петр Петрович</initials>

<role>рецензент</role>

</author>


</authors>
```

Мне нужно удалить полностью тег `<author>`, в котором содержится `<role>рецензент</role>`. Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

    tree = ET.parse('рецензенты.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    parent_map = dict((c, p) for p in tree.getiterator() for c in p)

    iterator = list(root.getiterator('author'))

for item in iterator:
    old = item.find('role')
    if old is None:
        continue
        text = old.text
        if 'рецензент' in text:
            parent_map[item].remove(item)
            continue

    tree.write('out.xml')
```

Хоть, этот код работает без ошибок, но теги не удаляются.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту задачу. Должно получиться вот так:

```
<authors>


<author lang="RU" num="1">

<lastname>Иванов</lastname>

<initials>Иван Иванович</initials>

</author>


</authors>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка возникает из-за отсутствия проверки существования тэга `role`. Так в приведённом примере, первый элемент `author` данного тэга не содержит, поэтому переменная `old == None`, но вместо того чтобы эту ситуацию отследить, происходит попытка чтения атрибута `text`, которого не существует. Достаточно вставить такую проверку для предотвращения этой ошибки:

```
if old is None:
    continue
```

Если не учитывать кодировки, то код должен получиться таким:

```
tree = ET.parse('рецензенты.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
parent_map = dict((c, p) for p in tree.iter() for c in p)

iterator = list(root.getiterator('author'))

for item in iterator:
    old = item.find('role')
    if old is None:
        continue
    text = old.text
    if 'рецензент' in text:
        parent_map[item].remove(item)
        continue

tree.write('out.xml')
```

Comment: благодарю за комментарий. Да, ошибка действительно пропала. Спасибо. Я правильно понимаю,что код теперь будет такой:`for item in iterator:
    old = item.find('role')
    if old is None:
        continue
        text = old.text
        if 'рецензент' in text:
            parent_map[item].remove(item)
            continue
`

Comment: ...да. Правильно.

Comment: в таком случае, ничего не происходит. Теги не удаляются. Сейчас поправлю вопрос.

Comment: Тэги удаляются, если у вас присутствуют ошибки, возможно проблемы с кодировкой документов.

Comment: выражаю Вам огромную благодарность!!! Спасибо большое, всё работает!!!